# Booting into a Graphical Based Program in Debian (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, boot, debian

I am trying to boot into chromium on a Raspberry Pi running debian. However on boot it goes to a full screen command line with no graphical display. I have in `/etc/init.d/` a script that starts up chromium on boot, however this fails to work as it there is no graphical environment started therefore it fails to start. Is there a way to boot Chrome on startup in a graphical environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Raspian, the Debian image for Raspberry Pi, you can run raspi-config and check to make sure your Pi is configured to run in desktop mode, as that is what it sounds like you are trying to do.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

from the terminal should do the trick. The link below explains how to toggle boot mode:

http://www.dingleberrypi.com/2012/09/tutorial-prepare-your-raspberry-pi-to-become-a-web-server/

I dont think it is possible to stay in 'boot to console' mode and still be able to open a gui application on startup, it that is what you are trying to do...

Hope this helps,

nim

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Will booting to desktop require any form of login? I want it so that when it boots up it goes right to chrome with no login needed.

Comment: That depends on whether the user account you are logging in with has a password; 'out of the box' the default pi user account did not require a password IIRC. If you find that the account does need a password to log in, then I would suggest just creating a new user and then setting that user to not require a password. This is so that you will have a user account that can log in without a password and that does not have admin rights, and you would still have a known user account that I am assuming **does** have admin rights. Does the account you are using currently require a password to log in?

Comment: Yes, the account I have which has admin access does have a password. I n fact by default Raspbian has the user pi's password set to `raspberry` though I have changed it from this. If I create an account with no password how would it know to boot into the desktop environment using that account?

Comment: I have never tried to do this, and am unsure how. I also dont know if you will become barred from root access if you wipe the password from the pi account without another account in the sudoers file. You may want to post another question about debian + user accounts and passwords. In any case if you still wanted to try (though i don't advise it without more research, just to be safe), here goes; To remove the password from an account type this in the terminal: `passwd -d username` replace username with the real account name. You will now be able to log in without a password